# Proving a kernel matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $m$ vectors $x_1, x_2,...,x_m$ in n dimensional boolean space. I am trying to prove that gram/kernel matrix $G$ is positive semidefinite, such that

$$G_{ij} = \frac{<\vec x_i,\vec x_j>}{<\vec x_i,\vec x_i> + <\vec x_j, \vec x_j> - <\vec x_i, \vec x_j>}$$

As $G$ is real symetric matrix. Now as its easy to see that diagonal enteries of $G$ are 1 so all first order principal minors are non negative. 
Similarly off diagonal entries are greater than equal to 0 and less than equal to 1, so all second order principle 2nd order minors are also non negative.

Now my question is how to extend this reasoning in more general $m\ x\ m$ case, or there is another more concise way to prove or disprove?

Also I would like to add one more thing $x_i$ are non zero vectors

Thanks

Comment: no 2 in the denominator?

Comment: Not in this particular case

Comment: I take it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem didn't work?

Comment: Taking $A = \pmatrix{I&-1/2\,I\\-1/2\,I&I}$, the denominator can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{x_i\\x_j}^*A \pmatrix{x_i \\ x_j}
$$